# Client Side React App fetch from Server Side Generated Firestore Emulator

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I currently have a React App with firebase initialized.  I am initializing my react application using a utility file like so:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/firestore'
import 'firebase/storage'

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_FIREBASE_APP_ID
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

if (window.location.hostname === 'localhost') {
  console.log('testing locally -- hitting local firestore emulators')
  firebase.firestore().settings({
    host: 'localhost:8080',
    ssl: false
  })
}

export const db = firebase.firestore()
export const storage = firebase.storage()
export default firebase
```

As you can see in the above code, I am telling my client-side to use localhost:8080(port where firestore emulator is running) as opposed to the production database.  When I run the emulator from my server side, the firestore emulator boots up on port:8080 successfully.  The issue is, on the client side when trying to fetch from the server side generated emulator I receieve the following error:

```
FirebaseError: 
false for 'list' @ L5
    at new n (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:1381:19)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:12934:18
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:12935:10
    at n.onMessage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:12983:6)
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:12846:18
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:12884:29
    at http://localhost:3000/static/js/1.chunk.js:7563:25
```

Is this a permissions issue? if so, does anyone have a solution? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it looks like a security rule prevents accessing your data.
To make sure you can try to allow access to everything, in your firestore.rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

To learn more about security rules: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started